# How to save Map to Shared Preferences?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have an `Map<Integer, User>` with custom values. Each User contains variety of strings and numbers. I can save a singel User but safe the entire Map is difficult. (I save a lot of other objects this way by using the SharedPreferences but I can't figure out how to save my entire Map this way. Is this possible? Maybe SharedPreferences isn't the way to go about this? Is there a simpler method?)

**Shared Preference Class:**

**Map**

```
public void saveUserMap(Map<Integer, User> userMap){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        editor.putInt("userID", userMap.get(userMap).getUserID());
        editor.putString("firstName", userMap.get(userMap).getFirstName());
        editor.putString("userName", userMap.get(userMap).getUserName());
        editor.putString("birthDate", userMap.get(userMap).getBirthDate());
        editor.putString("gender", userMap.get(userMap).getGender());
        editor.putString("country", userMap.get(userMap).getCountry());
        editor.putString("aboutmeText", userMap.get(userMap).getAboutmeText());
        editor.putString("status", userMap.get(userMap).getStatus());

        editor.apply();
    }
```

**Single User:**

```
public void saveUser(User user){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        editor.putInt("userID", user.getUserID());
        editor.putString("firstName", user.getFirstName());
        editor.putString("userName", user.getUserName());
        editor.putString("birthDate", user.getBirthDate());
        editor.putString("gender", userMap.get(userMap).getGender());
        editor.putString("country", user.getCountry());
        editor.putString("aboutmeText", user.getAboutmeText());
        editor.putString("status", user.getStatus());
       
        editor.apply();
}
```

**Save a Single User is possible:**

```
SharedPrefManager.getInstance(TestRequest.this)
                            .saveUser(standardResponse.getUser().get(0));
```

**Save User Map crash:**

```
SharedPrefManager.getInstance(TestRequest.this)
                            .saveUserMap(standardResponse.getUser());
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can serialise user object to json(using GSON or Moshi) and save the JSON into shared Pref.

```
public void saveUserMap(User user){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        editor.putString("mUser", new Gson().toJson(user));

        editor.apply();
    }
```

---

Other options for save objects are a number of ORMs for Android (ORMLite, greenDAO, Sugar ORM, ActiveAndroid, etc.)